# HQL join query to join to a single row of many to one relationship

Tags: sql, hibernate, join, hql

This HQL query has been driving me up a wall, and I hope someone can help me out. Here is my data model:

```
public class Record {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<RecordFieldData> recordFieldData;
}

public class RecordFieldData {
    private int id;
    private String data;
    private Record record;
    private RecordTypeField type;
}

public class RecordTypeField {
    private int id;
    private String dataType;
}
```

Here is some data:

```
Record
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | name                                |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Abc                                 |
| 2       | 123                                 |
| 3       | Xyz                                 |
-------------------------------------------------

RecordFieldData
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | record_id  | data         | type_id |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 1          | Blue         | 1       |
| 2       | 1          | Round        | 2       |
| 3       | 2          | Red          | 1       |
| 4       | 2          | Square       | 2       |
| 5       | 3          | White        | 1       |
| 6       | 3          | Oval         | 2       |
-------------------------------------------------

RecordTypeField
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | dataType                            |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Color                               |
| 2       | Shape                               |
-------------------------------------------------
```

What I need is a list of Records that are sorted by RecordField.data of a certain type. For example, sort the Records on RecordField.data but only for RecordFieldData of type 'color'. RecordFieldData.data does not have to be returned in the query, I can get that later, but I need the sort to happen in the query that retrieves the records (otherwise pagination won't work). Keep in mind RecordFieldData of a certain type can be missing for a Record but I still want the record in the list.

I tried this query but I am getting duplicate records because it is joining RecordFieldData rows that I do not want:

```
SELECT r FROM Record r 
LEFT JOIN r.recordFieldData AS field 
LEFT JOIN field.type AS typeField WITH typeField.dataType = 'color' 
ORDER BY LOWER(field.data)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Just saw your requirement of needing to return all records. So replacing `LEFT JOIN` with `JOIN` as I initially suggested won't work.

Try using `DISTINCT` instead

```
SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Record r 
LEFT JOIN r.recordFieldData AS field 
LEFT JOIN field.type AS typeField WITH typeField.dataType = 'color' 
ORDER BY LOWER(field.data)
```

**EDIT 2**

I think `LEFT JOIN FETCH` needs to be used, though I'm not sure why it gave you an error the last time. Maybe something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Record r 
LEFT JOIN FETCH r.recordFieldData AS field 
LEFT JOIN FETCH field.type AS typeField WITH typeField.dataType = 'color' 
ORDER BY LOWER(field.data)
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for this question...I actually have a more complicated query which builds on this data model, should I create a new question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293418/hql-double-join-query-with-one-to-many-relationship

Much obliged!

Comment: So, this actually doesn't work. It will always sort the same no matter which data type I am trying to sort on.

Comment: So I think the problem is I only want to left join with RecordFieldData where RecordFieldData.type.dataType is a certain value. Right now it is left joining with all recordfielddata.

Comment: @Osman try update, if that doesn't work try `ORDER BY r.recordFieldData.data`

Comment: The fetch still doesn't work, the update isn't working without the fetch either. Hibernate is complaining that field.type.dataType is not part of the join (with-clause expressions did not reference from-clause element to which the with-clause was associated)

Comment: @Osman one more update, if this doesn't work i'm out of ideas :)

Comment: OK I figured out why the fetch wasn't working....it was something I was doing later in the code, I was reusing the query for a COUNT. So the 2nd FETCH is throwing a different error: "with-clause not allowed on fetched associations; use filters"

Comment: @Osman if the 1st fetch is working, maybe remove the 2nd fetch. because you really just need the 1st one since you're referencing `field.data` in your `order by`

Comment: I think the issue is that is sorting on all of the field data together so it is always sorted the same way. Then the DISTINCT only returns the first row for each record, so the records aren't actually sorted properly.

Comment: The only way to do this I think is to have the left join properly filtered so that it only left joins with a subset of RecordFieldData. HQL doesn't seem to support this.

Comment: @Osman sorry i'm out of ideas, please unaccept my answer so I can delete it as it's not correct

Comment: Please don't delete, I think this discussion could be useful for somoeone else trying to answer.