# HQL double join query with one to many relationship

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

This HQL query has been driving me up a wall, and I hope someone can help me out. Here is my data model:

```
public class Record {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<RecordFieldData> recordFieldData;
}

public class RecordFieldData {
    private int id;
    private String data;
    private Record record;
    private RecordTypeField type;
    private User relatedUser;
}

public class RecordTypeField {
    private int id;
    private String dataType;
}
```

Here is some data:

```
Record
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | name                                |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Round Cookie                        |
| 2       | Square Cookie                       |
| 3       | Oval Cookie                         |
-------------------------------------------------

RecordFieldData
--------------------------------------------------------
| id      | record_id | data       | type_id | user_id |
--------------------------------------------------------
| 1       | 1         |            | 1       | 1       |
| 2       | 1         | Round      | 2       |         |
| 3       | 2         |            | 1       | 2       |
| 4       | 2         | Square     | 2       |         |
| 5       | 3         |            | 1       |         |
| 6       | 3         | Oval       | 2       |         |
--------------------------------------------------------

RecordTypeField
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | dataType                            |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | Creator                             |
| 2       | Shape                               |
| 3       | Owner                               |
-------------------------------------------------

User
-------------------------------------------------
| id      | username                            |
-------------------------------------------------
| 1       | MilaK                               |
| 2       | JenniferA                           |
-------------------------------------------------
```

What I need is a list of Records that are sorted by the Creator's username. So the RecordFieldData.relatedUser.username, but only for type Creator. The username does not have to be returned in the query, I can get that later, but I need the sort to happen in the query that retrieves the records (otherwise pagination won't work). Keep in mind RecordFieldData of a certain type can be missing for a Record but I still want the record in the list.

I tried this query but it doesn't seem to be sorting properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r FROM Record r 
LEFT JOIN r.recordFieldData AS field 
LEFT JOIN field.relatedUser AS relatedUser 
LEFT JOIN field.type as typeField WITH typeField.dataType = 'Creator' 
ORDER BY LOWER(relatedUser.username)
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I figured out why the sort isn't working properly, but don't know how to fix it. See my edit at the end.

Comment: Actually, my client was doing the improper sorting. The data returned from the query does not appear to be sorted by username at all. I've redacted my previous edit.

Comment: Do you want to sort by the creator's username or by the username of `relatedUser`?

Comment: Username of relatedUser but only for RecordFieldData.type is Creator