# How to select a single child in hibernate with one to many association

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, one-to-many, hibernate-criteria

Say I have a "Class" object with a one to many relationship with "Students".

```
public class Class implements java.io.Serializable {

private String classId;
private List<Student> student; 

public Class() {
}

public Class(String classId) {
    this.classId = classId;
}


@Id

@Column(name = "CLASS_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
public String getClassId() {
    return this.classId;
}

public void setClassId(String classId) {
    this.classId = classId;
}


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="classId")
public List<Student> getStudent() {
    return student;
}
```

There can be up to 200k "Students" per class. I want to retrieve a "Class" with only it's first student. But when I do so I get a single "Class" with ALL of it's "Students" instead of just ONE.

```
criteria = session.createCriteria(Class.class, "class").add(Restrictions.eq("class.classId", "0002")).setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

This causes the DB to timeout because it takes too long to query the DB with over 200k "Students" Is there a way to Query the DB in Hibernate to retrieve a specific "Class" with only one of it's "Students" without retrieving all 200k so the DB does not time out? I would prefer to do so with Criteria, but if not is there a way to do so with HQL?

Comment: This is not clear `want to retrieve a "Class" with only it's first student`. It is mapped as a Set and Set does not maintain any order. What do you mean by first student? Is there any column in student table that maintains the order? Regarding the solution, make your association as bidirectional and you need to build your criteria from `Student.class` instead of `Class.class`. Once you get the student you can navigate to Class entity.That should help.

Comment: You're right I should be using List not Set. But can you give me an example how how to do the bidirectional association and build criteria from Student.class?

Comment: Once you make it bidirectional as described [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional) and adding `idx` field to Student as `OrderColumn`, you can use `session1.createCriteria(MyStudent.class, "s").createAlias("s.myClass",  "c").add(Restrictions.eq("c.id", "1")).add(Restrictions.eq("s.idx", 1)).setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);` to build criteria from Student.class, as an example.

Answer (score 0):

I've been reading this very interesting article on the subject

http://www.theotherian.com/2013/07/hibernate-joins-maxresults.html

Applying the proposed solution in that article to your problem:

```
// works with FetchType.LAZY and FetchType.EAGER
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CLASS_ID")
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@BatchSize(size = 1)
private List<Students> students;

public List<Students> getStudents() { return students; }
public void setStudents(List<Students> students) { this.students = students; }
```

I think that this way, you will obtain a list with only one student using your criteria to retrieve an specific Class

Comment: Does this then limit my options of filling in data to only ever be able to  update one child if I wish to eventually do updates as well as selects?

Comment: @user2719805 But you don't have to update students accesing to Class entity. Maybe you have to apply the approach stated by Madhusudana Reddy Sunnapu.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried HQL? May be below post helps you in understanding HQL.

[HQL join query to join to a single row of many to one relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24291060/hql-join-query-to-join-to-a-single-row-of-many-to-one-relationship)